# IBM cognos analytics 11.1 group_cocat

Tags: group-by, string-concatenation, cognos

I have a Table  with three string columns (ID, name, books).If I wrote SQL, I would want the result of the following query:

```sql
SELECT ID
, name
, group_concat(books) as concat_groups
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID
, name
```

However, I cannot write an SQL query and have to use a 'drag and drop' query from a table that is a part of a preloaded data model.
I do not find any function to concatenate strings in the summarize properties.

Comment: You can use functions in an expression.  Depending on the database you are using the group_concat might be available.  You can also try LISTAGG.  
For example, SELECT ID, name, listagg(trim(books), ', ') as my group FROM Table GROUP BY ID,name.   Next, you can have this set up in a query subject in either Framework Manager or using data modules

Comment: `group_concat` is a MySQL function.  But it's also an aggregation function.  It's unlikely Cognos will allow you to use a vendor-specific aggregation function outside of pass-thru SQL.  But your question also lacks detail.  What version of Cognos are you using? 
 Do you want distinct values?  What delimiter should be used?  Do you require the values are in a specific order?  And I doubt drag-and-drop is your only option.  I'd guess you can create additional queries and manually type into expression dialogs.  How much experience do you have developing Cognos reports?

Comment: And please tag the question more appropriately.  `cognos` is a general product line including products like Cognos Business Intelligence, Cognos Planning, Transformer, Cognos Analytics, etc.  If you are using the modern reporting product, that's probably Cognos Analytics.  Look for other tags like `cognos-bi` or `cognos-11`